# GeoServer upgraded to 2.17, WFS extra dimension returned in linestrings, causing exception Invalid ordinate index: 3 calling geom.Coordinate.setM()

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I've recently upgraded an older Geoserver from 2.8 to 2.17. I simply downloaded the latest WAR file.  When it started, it used the same data_dir folder, and all looked great.  This may be relevant to my issue...

A WFS query to a MultiLineString shapefile layer now returns data where each point of the linestring contains three values, rather than just two.  In cases where the query returns data successfully, the third parameter is always zero.  There are some lines, however, that throw the exception shown below in GeoServer instead.

I also have a freshly installed 2.16 GeoServer that contains the same layer based on the exact same shape file.  WFS queries to this machine return successfully for all of the linestrings, and they return with points of just two dimensions (as expected).

I checked the layer definition and it does NOT include elevation or any other additional dimensions.

Here is an example when the data is returned from a query of this layer on the 2.17 GeoServer, note each coordinate has an array of three values:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "myLayer.6005",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiLineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            1013611.038,
                            852206.36300001,
                            0
                        ],
                        [
                            1013601.589,
                            852206.442,
                            0
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "the_geom",
            "properties": {
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalFeatures": 1,
    "numberMatched": 1,
    "numberReturned": 1,
    "timeStamp": "2020-05-13T15:37:44.822Z",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2234"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full Exception, I assume it is because the third parameter (whereever it comes from) was an illegal value.  I don't know how to find out what it is...:

```
2020-05-13 18:15:51,462 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ordinate index: 3
    at org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate.setM(Coordinate.java:214)
    at org.locationtech.jts.geom.impl.PackedCoordinateSequence.getCoordinate(PackedCoordinateSequence.java:107)
    at org.locationtech.jts.operation.predicate.RectangleIntersectsSegmentVisitor.checkIntersectionWithSegments(RectangleIntersects.java:327)
    at org.locationtech.jts.operation.predicate.RectangleIntersectsSegmentVisitor.checkIntersectionWithLineStrings(RectangleIntersects.java:317)
    at org.locationtech.jts.operation.predicate.RectangleIntersectsSegmentVisitor.visit(RectangleIntersects.java:310)
    at org.locationtech.jts.geom.util.ShortCircuitedGeometryVisitor.applyTo(ShortCircuitedGeometryVisitor.java:35)
    at org.locationtech.jts.operation.predicate.RectangleIntersects.intersects(RectangleIntersects.java:110)
    at org.locationtech.jts.operation.predicate.RectangleIntersects.intersects(RectangleIntersects.java:58)
    at org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry.intersects(Geometry.java:745)
    at org.geotools.filter.spatial.BBOXImpl.basicEvaluate(BBOXImpl.java:117)
    at org.geotools.filter.spatial.BBOXImpl.evaluateInternal(BBOXImpl.java:107)
    at org.geotools.filter.GeometryFilterImpl.evaluate(GeometryFilterImpl.java:210)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureReader.buildFeature(ShapefileFeatureReader.java:262)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.IndexedShapefileFeatureReader.hasNext(IndexedShapefileFeatureReader.java:97)
    at org.geotools.data.ReTypeFeatureReader.hasNext(ReTypeFeatureReader.java:187)
    at org.geotools.data.MaxFeatureReader.hasNext(MaxFeatureReader.java:77)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.size(ContentFeatureCollection.java:241)
    at org.geotools.data.crs.ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.size(ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.GetFeature.run(GetFeature.java:682)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService20.getFeature(DefaultWebFeatureService20.java:109)
```

Here is the query, (it's on a private server so you can't try it yourself...)
http://myGeoServer:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=JSON&typeNames=SITE:MyLayer&srsName=EPSG:2234&bbox=-8092515.10277076,5130597.052061503,-8092507.994851346,5130604.159980916,EPSG:3857

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: closing this to point at the later question which has open data attached so it can be tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoTools (the underlying library of GeoServer) was recently [upgraded to handle Shapefiles with M and Z values](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6362). So you are probably seeing a side effect of this change. It looks like your shapefile has M (and/or Z) values - you can check this using `ogrinfo` or look at the layer properties in QGIS.

If you can create a small test dataset the demonstrates the problem please [open an issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/issues) with it attached and I'll take a look to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, that seems likely related... Using ogrinfo -al myShapeFile.shp I just looked at some random features, and the linestring's points seem to have just 2 dimensions.  Example:  LINESTRING (1017866.027 845370.859,1017873.141 845368.886)  I know the source of this data and it would make no sense at all to have an m or z value.  is there some other option to ogrinfo that would provide the info about z or m values?

Comment: I installed a new 2.17 geoserver, added the shape file layer, and recreated the problem.  In QGIS I opened the shape file, Exported it to a new shape file, added that to the 2.17 geoserver, and the query no longer looks for or returns the z/m value.  So I can work around the issue by simply recreating a QGIS generated version of the two shapefiles I have experiencing this issue.  If you would like a private copy of my shapefile to investigate why GeoServer thinks there is a z value when there is not, let me know how you would like to receive it.  Otherwise, thanks for the help.

Comment: Regarding opening an issue - I've created an atlassian account but don't seem authorized to open an issue for geoserver (I'm a community user...)

Comment: can you send me a copy of (or part of) the shapefile and details of where it came from I'll take a look.